# How to retrieve only ticket number from string

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have the following pipeline step which run a Regex

```
- TICKET_NAME="$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -E 's~^(.*/){0,1}((ABV|ASD|WSX)-[0-9]{2,6})-.*~\2~I')"
```

Basically, the `$BRANCH_NAME` can be the following

```
fix/ABV-123-test-version
ABV-4233-test-another-thing
feature/-ASD-my-feature
```

What I would like is, to always retrieve the ticket number which is always starting with `ABV|ASD|WSX` and always end after the number.

so `ABS-123` or `ASD-3423` the number can be any number but it will always be the same pattern.

my current regex works, but it also capute the prefix so `fix/ABV-123`

I would like only the `ABV-123`

Comment: This is bash not (windows) batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En 's~([^/]*/)?([AW][BS][VDX]-[0-9]+).*~\2~p' input_file
ABV-123
ABV-4233
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting `RS`(Record separator) to `((A(BV|SD))|WSX)-[0-9]+` to get ABV OR ASD OR WSX followed by a `-` followed by 1 or more digits and then in main program printing RT values if its not null.

```bash
awk -v RS='((A(BV|SD))|WSX)-[0-9]+' RT'{print RT}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier with `grep -o`:

```bash
grep -Eo '(ABV|ASD|WSX)-[0-9]+' file

ABV-123
ABV-4233
```

Comment: thanks this is actually indeed better, but since asked for sed I approved the other one. But I replaced with this.